# Update value of a single entry in a List<Map<String, dynamic>> in dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have a list of type `Map<String,dynamic>`, I fill this list with `List.filled`.

```
[{gstatus: 1, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: }]
```

But if I want to change e.g. the value "vermerk" of the second entry  of the list with ".update()", all values of the key "vermerk" change like:

```
[{gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}]
```

I would like to have the following result

```
[{gstatus: 1, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: }]
```

Here the Code

```
void main() {
  
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> deviceForm;
  
  deviceForm = List.filled(4,
          {"gstatus": 1, "vermerk": ""});
  
  print(deviceForm);
  
  deviceForm[1].update('vermerk', (value) => 'test');
  
  print(deviceForm);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very interesting issue, seems like List.filled will produce identical data, because of this somehow every data will be changed if you try to change one of them... and once i check like this, it return TRUE

`print(deviceForm[1] == deviceForm[2]); //TRUE`

but i try another shot with List.generate, the result will be different

`print(deviceForm[1] == deviceForm[2]); //FALSE`

If you have specific reason why you use List.filled, maybe this answer will be useless, or in case you have no problem to switch using List.generate, it will solve your problem

`deviceForm = List.generate(4, (index) => {"gstatus": 1, "vermerk": ""});`

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to point exactly at the object and then overwrite the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use generate and update

```dart
void main() {
  
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> deviceForm = List.generate(4,
         (index)=> {"gstatus": 1, "vermerk": ""});
  
  print(deviceForm);
  
  deviceForm[1].update('vermerk', (value) => 'test');
  
  print(deviceForm);
  //Output : [{gstatus: 1, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: }]
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work like this! when i do it like this i also get the following output ´´´[{gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}, {gstatus: 1, vermerk: test}]´´´

Comment: Thank you very much. I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough points yet.

Answer (score 0):

> `List.filled`: All elements of the created list share the **same [fill] value**.

The issue lies on `List.filled`, you can use `List.generate` instead

```dart
  deviceForm1 = List.generate(
    3,
    (_) => {"gstatus": 1, "vermerk": ""},
  );
```

Or create new map and assign on index 1.

```dart
void main() {
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> deviceForm;

  deviceForm = List.filled(2, {"gstatus": 0, "vermerk": ""});

  print(deviceForm[1] == Map.from(deviceForm[0])); //false
  print(deviceForm[1] == deviceForm[0]); //true

  deviceForm[1] = Map.from(deviceForm[1])
    ..update("vermerk",
        (value) => "Test"); // we are creating new Map and assingng it

  print(deviceForm);
  //[{gstatus: 0, vermerk: }, {gstatus: 0, vermerk: newValue}]
}
```

And check these questions

- [What is the true meaning of pass-by-reference in modern languages like Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58966090/10157127)
- [Is Dart pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58966090/10157127)

I am taking some parts

> like many other languages (e.g. Java, Python), is technically pass-by-value where the "value" of an object is a reference to it. This is why functions can mutate arguments passed by the caller.  However, in these languages where everything is an object and where there are not separate pointer types, "pass-by-value" and "pass-by-reference" can be confusing terms and are not particularly meaningful. A lot of Python programmers instead use the term pass-by-assignment[..ReadMore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281531/10157127)

> The pass-references-by-value behavior is common to a lot of modern languages (Smalltalk, Java, Ruby, Python…). When you pass an object, you're actually passing-by-value (therefore copying) the contents of your variable, which is a pointer to the object. You never control where objects really exist.[...ReadMore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25171102/10157127)