# Flutter can not dispose VideoPlayerController

Tags: flutter, dart, dispose

I am getting an exception thrown while using a back button after disposing of my VideoPlayerController.

I have my VideoPlayer and VideoPlayerController set up like this:

```
 String url;
 var plan;
_VideoPlayerScreenState(this.url,{this.plan});

 Future<Null> OnWillPop(){

_controller.dispose();

if(plan!=null)
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
ListSession(plan :plan)));
else
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
ListMoves()));

}
VideoPlayerController _controller;
Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

@override
void initState() {
 _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
  url,
 );

// Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
_initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

// Use the controller to loop the video.
_controller.setLooping(true);
_controller.play();
super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
 print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
_controller.dispose();
 super.dispose();
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return WillPopScope(onWillPop: OnWillPop,child:Scaffold(

   // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
   // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
   body: FutureBuilder(
    future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
        // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
        return Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
        // loading spinner.
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  ),
 ));
}
```

but when I press the back button, I get this error:

```
Another exception was thrown: A VideoPlayerController was used after being disposed.
```

How do I properly dispose of my VideoPlayerController and be able to incorporate the back button?

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955831/flutter-video-player-dispose/58959097#58959097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
and mark unmark `Navigator.push` / `Navigator.pushReplacement` to check effect 
In your case, you do not need to dispose of `controller`, because `controller` is local to this page, you can just do `_controller.pause()` 
You use `Navigator.push` go to next page means you will `pop` from next page 
If you `dispose controller` and set `controller` to `null` successfully, when pop from next page, you will get an error because `initState` will not be called again, `controller` will not init again

If you use `Navigator.pushReplacement`, `dispose` will be called automatically, 
You can see console show _controller.dispose in demo code.

working demo 
you can see when back from `ListMove` page, video still can play

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoPlayerApp());

class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoPlayerScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  VideoPlayerController _oldController;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("initState");
    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4',
    );

    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("_controller.dispose");
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    //_initializeVideoPlayerFuture = null;
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        await _controller.pause();
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListMoves()));

        /*Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListMoves()));*/
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Butterfly Video'),
        ),
        // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
        // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
              // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              );
            } else {
              // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
              // loading spinner.
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
            // correct icon is shown.
            setState(() {
              // If the video is playing, pause it.
              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                _controller.pause();
              } else {
                // If the video is paused, play it.
                _controller.play();
              }
            });
          },
          // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListMoves extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List Movies'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch screen'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```